# What causes myalgia after strength training?

Tags: pain, exercise, inflammation, strength-training

You can get muscle pain 24 hours after strength training. As far as I know, this is caused by some cracks in the muscle.

Pain is often caused or initiated by inflammation, by which some enzymes and other molecules attach to the nociceptors and pain nerves.

I've read that, in the past, some scientists have argued that there is no inflammation at all in the case of myalgia after exercise. So my question is: is this true, and if so, and what else causes these pains the day after strength training?

Comment: Could you please clarify sources where you found the information you're using (in particular, the arguments against inflammation)?